# Powershell Get-EventLog find event with the matching string in its message

Tags: powershell

I need to look through eventLog security ID 4648, and find the last time the user connected to the machine.

Currently this is my code:

```
$Values = invoke-command  -ComputerName $ComputerName {Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceID 4648 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Message| ForEach-Object {if($_.Log -match "$String2"){
$_
Break }}}
$Values
```

The aim was to go through each log until a log where the message has the previously defined username is found, and then stop going through EventLog and return that log.

This is working well, except its not matching the correct log with the specified string.

Is there a way to improve how the matching works? So it actually finds the correct log with the specified user?

Comment: `Message` is of type string, so you can't dereference the `Log` property on `$_` -> `(Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceID 4648 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty message -first 1 ).GetType().Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Fill in the regex for the userName
$userName = "userName"
$Values = @(invoke-command  -ComputerName $ComputerName { 
    Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceID 4648 |  Where-Object { $_.message -match $Using:userName } | Select-Object -First 1)
}
```

Your above sample won't work since `message` is of type `string`, therefore it doesn't have a `Log` property. Since we want `$userName` to be avaiable for read access on the remote machine we can use the `$Using:` syntax. To break the pipeline "iteration" I'm using `Select-Object -First 1` which will return the first object passing the `Where-Object`clause.

Resulting from that `$Values` points to a collection of (deserialized) objects (using the `@()` operator) of type:

```
 TypeName: System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry#Security/Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing/4648
```

Which means you can change the `-First` parameter to e.g. 10 and sort the result on the client machine:

```
$Values | sort TimeGenerated -Descending
```

If you want to know which properties are available you can use:

```
> $Values | gm


   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry#Security/Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing/4648

Name                      MemberType     Definition
----                      ----------     ----------
Disposed                  Event          System.EventHandler Disposed(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
CreateObjRef              Method         System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)
Dispose                   Method         void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()
Equals                    Method         bool Equals(System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry otherEntry), bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method         int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method         System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetObjectData             Method         void ISerializable.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
GetType                   Method         type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method         System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
ToString                  Method         string ToString()
Category                  Property       string Category {get;}
CategoryNumber            Property       int16 CategoryNumber {get;}
Container                 Property       System.ComponentModel.IContainer Container {get;}
Data                      Property       byte[] Data {get;}
EntryType                 Property       System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType EntryType {get;}
Index                     Property       int Index {get;}
InstanceId                Property       long InstanceId {get;}
MachineName               Property       string MachineName {get;}
Message                   Property       string Message {get;}
ReplacementStrings        Property       string[] ReplacementStrings {get;}
Site                      Property       System.ComponentModel.ISite Site {get;set;}
Source                    Property       string Source {get;}
TimeGenerated             Property       datetime TimeGenerated {get;}
TimeWritten               Property       datetime TimeWritten {get;}
UserName                  Property       string UserName {get;}
EventID                   ScriptProperty System.Object EventID {get=$this.get_EventID() -band 0xFFFF;}
```

Hope that helps.